# WiX v3.6 PermissionEx - Sddl attribute required?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Really?

I am trying to do something like this -

```
<PermissionEx
              User="Authenticated Users"
              GenericAll="yes"
              ServiceChangeConfig="yes"
              ServiceEnumerateDependents="yes"
              ChangePermission="yes"
              ServiceInterrogate="yes"
              ServicePauseContinue="yes"
              ServiceQueryConfig="yes"
              ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
              ServiceStart="yes"
              ServiceStop="yes" />
```

and it is giving me

> The required attribute 'Sddl' is missing.

Not familiar with Sddl. How do I create an Sddl string to match the above permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PermissionEx is the tag for MSI 5.0's MsiLockPermissionsEx functionality, which requires an SDDL string. There's also a PermissionEx tag in WixUtilExtension, which allows similar functionality on all versions of MSI. You're using the former with the latter's attributes. If you want the WixUtilExtension variant of PermissionEx, use the WixUtilExtension namespace:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
...
<util:PermissionEx ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use the API [ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376397.aspx) or work it out in your head following the format described on MSDN article [Security Descriptor String Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379570.aspx). Or look for examples of what you need online.